# If a function call is made inside a spark application, on which component will the return data reside?

Tags: apache-spark

If i create a `List` or a function call which returns a `List` in Spark Application, where will it create the List. On Driver or on Executor/ Worker Node?

```
SparkSession sessn = SparkSession.builder().appName("Teradata JDBC").master("local").getOrCreate();
List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
List l1 = object.func();  --> Function call which returns list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Any user written code for data fetch outside RDD/Dataframe/Dataset's `foreach` loop or any RDD iterator will be on Driver.
Hence `List l1 = object.func();` will reside on l1
If you are looking to distribute it either convert it to dataset or use 
`sc.parallelize(l1)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. A follow up question on the same. Will this function call (which returns a list) be part of DAG or Lineage Graph? I think it should not be part of DAG since it never resides on Worker/Executor. Just wanted to be more sure about it with your inputs.

Comment: it should not be as those graphs of task/Job only consists of operations/function executable on RDDs @shankar